# Expression must have pointer-to-object type in C++

Tags: c++

I tried looking this up beforehand and nothing seemed to work. I am just trying to make a function and there are apparently errors for int i under dotProduct. Does anybody know why this is happening?
`

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int inp,i,v,array1,array2,oo,test1;
    // Checking the input of the array size
    do {
        cout << "Enter Array size: ";
        cin >> inp;
        if (inp <= 0)
            cout << "Incorrect array size. Try Again \n";
    } while (inp <= 0);
    int *arr1;
    int *arr2;
    arr1 = new int[inp];
    arr2 = new int[inp];
    // Populating the arrays
    cout << "-----Begin Entering Array Elements-------- \n";
    cout << "Array 1: \n";
    for (i = 0; i <= (inp - 1); i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter element: ";
        cin >> v;
        arr1[i] = v;
    }
    cout << "Array 2: \n";
    for (i = 0; i <= (inp - 1); i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter element: ";
        cin >> v;
        arr2[i] = v;
    }
    // The dot product function
    int dotProduct(int *array1, int *array2, int size);
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= (inp - 1); i++)
        {
            oo = ((*array1[i]) * (*array2[i]));
            sum = sum + oo;
        }
    }
    test1 = dotProduct(arr1, arr2, inp);
    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error, where does it point to?

Comment: There are many things wrong, but `*array1[i]` with `array1` being an `int` is crazy talk.

Comment: Pointers are not arrays. The subscript `[]` operator already does the dereferencing.

Comment: @immibis Towards the *array1[i] and the second one, all under the dotProduct function.

Comment: Are you trying to define a local function?  `dotProduct` needs to be defined outside of `main`.

Comment: @ron I get that but how would I make oo take in arr1 and arr2 in the function?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I can try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function ends with a semicolon:

```
int dotProduct(int* parray1, int *parray2, int size);
```

thus making it a declaration only. And it is inside the `main()` function which is also wrong. The subscript operator `[]` already does the dereferencing so no need to dereference twice, should be:

```
array1[i] * array2[i]
```

Finally, your function needs to return the `sum` and the `for` condition needs to be changed to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

and you should `delete` the memory allocated for `arr1;` and `arr2` in your main. Here is how the function might look like:

```
int dotProduct(int *array1, int *array2, int size) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += array1[i] * array2[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You're right. I put it outside main() and it worked perfectly. Dumb mistake on my part, even if it is my first time making a function in this language. Thank you.